# Elasticsearch not ready on CircleCI

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, circleci, circleci-2.0

When I run CircleCI, the first few tests fail due to Elasticsearch not being fully set up yet.

Usually I would use the `dockerize` library to wait for Elasticsearch to be finished, however this does not seem to detect Elasticsearch. Any ideas why? The dockerize command simply times out. However, the Elasticsearch container seems to be running because if I do not wait, eventually Elasticsearch starts to work with the tests.

Here is my docker file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    parallelism: 3
    working_directory: ~/export-opportunities
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.5.5-node
        environment:
          BUNDLE_JOBS: 3
          BUNDLE_RETRY: 3
          BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
          PGHOST: localhost
          PGUSER: user
          RAILS_ENV: test
      - image: circleci/postgres:latest
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: user
          POSTGRES_DB:  circle_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      - image: circleci/redis:4.0.9
        environment:
          REDIS_URL: "redis://localhost:6379/"
      - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
        environment:
          cluster.name: elasticsearch
          xpack.security.enabled: false
          transport.host: localhost
          network.host: 127.0.0.1
          http.port: 9200
          discovery.type: single-node
    branches:
      only: chore/XOT-597-circleci
    steps:
      - checkout # check out the code in the project directory
      # restore bundle cache  
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - exops-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

      - run:
          name: Bundle Install
          command: bundle check || bundle install

      # store bundle cache
      - save_cache:
          key: exops-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths: 
            - vendor/bundle

      # Database setup
      - run:
          name: install dockerize
          command: wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
          environment:
            DOCKERIZE_VERSION: v0.3.0

      - run:
          name: Wait for DB
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m

      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: |
            bundle exec rake db:create
            bundle exec rake db:migrate

      # Redis setup
      - run:
          name: Wait for Redis
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:6379 -timeout 1m
      # DOES NOT WORK:
      - run:
          name: Wait for Elasticsearch
          command: dockerize -wait http://localhost:9200 -timeout 2m

      # Run rspec in parallel 
      - run: |
          echo Running test ...
          bundle exec rspec --profile 10 \
                      --format RspecJunitFormatter \
                      --out test_results/rspec.xml \
                      --format progress \
                      $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)

      # Save test results for timing analysis
      - store_test_results:
          path: test_results
```

Note I've also tried `dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:9200 -timeout 2m`, and `dockerize -wait http://127.0.0.1:9200 -timeout 2m`, and `dockerize -wait tcp://127.0.0.1:9200 -timeout 2m` to no effect.

Comment: Hmm, strange. To get you going, put a `sleep 10` in place of the non-working `dockerize`. Then, when you get time, I wonder if it is worth trying any similar tools, e.g. the `waitforit` script.

Comment: How long does Elasticsearch take to get ready? I wonder if you have an edge case where it is taking more than 2m to start.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `sleep 10` and `sleep 100` however the issue persisted.

The issue was that the tests were running before the index was created. The index creation was being triggered by the first test to run, but took a few seconds, so the first few tests always failed.

My solution with this was to add the following code to trigger building the index, if not present, in `rails_helper.rb` which runs on starting the rails environment. For most other environments, the indices do exist so it does not slow down other processes.

```
# Build initial indices if not present, e.g. CircleCI
  [Opportunity, Subscription].each do |model|
    unless model.__elasticsearch__.index_exists? index: model.__elasticsearch__.index_name
      model.__elasticsearch__.create_index!(force: true)
      sleep 2
    end
  end
```